# How can I have a figure with caption inside a tcolorbox?

Tags: graphics, tcolorbox

I am trying to include a figure w/ caption inside a tcolorbox which wraps a definition environment.

My MWE is...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multido}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!5, arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, boxrule=0.5pt]
    \noindent\sffamily\upshape \textbf{Definition}
    \ifx\empty#1\empty\else\ (#1)\fi. % Theorem name (optional)
    \ \ignorespaces
}
{
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \par\nobreak
}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
Here is my definition

\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Hello}
\end{figure}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

Without the caption the image shows up, but if I add a caption the image disappears. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Instead of placing a `figure` environment inside a `tcolorbox` environment, have you considered doing the reverse — placing a `tcolorbox` inside a `figure`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`float.sty` with the option `H`, also an another suggestion, and the `MWE` is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{multido}
\usepackage{float}
\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!5, arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, boxrule=0.5pt]
    \noindent\sffamily\upshape \textbf{Definition}
    \ifx\empty#1\empty\else\ (#1)\fi. % Theorem name (optional)
    \ \ignorespaces
}
{
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \par\nobreak
}

\begin{document}
\begin{definition}
Here is my definition

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{example-image-a}
\caption{Hello}
\end{figure}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Note that option `H` placed the image at the exact place where you placed

Answer (score 4):

`\captionof` from `caption` package is your friend.

```tex
\documentclass{article}
% \usepackage{xcolor} % auto loaded by tcolorbox
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
% \usepackage{multido}

\usepackage[strut=off]{caption}

\newenvironment{definition}[1][]{
  \par\addvspace{\topsep}
  \begin{tcolorbox}[colback=yellow!5, arc=0pt, outer arc=0pt, boxrule=0.5pt]
    \noindent\sffamily\upshape \textbf{Definition}%
    % use \ifstrempty from etoolbox, which is auto loaded by tcolorbox
    \ifstrempty{#1}{}{\ (#1)}.% Theorem name (optional)
    \ \ignorespaces
}
{
  \end{tcolorbox}
  \par\nobreak
}


\begin{document}
\listoffigures % \captionof contributes to list of figures

\begin{definition}
Here is my definition

\begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=7.5cm]{example-image-a}
  \captionof{figure}{Hello}
\end{minipage}
\end{definition}
\end{document}
```

[image]